# Make the right side of a div as an arrow

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a simple div on a page:

```
<div>Some Text</div>
```

Is it possible, with CSS, to make it finish as an arrow. Something like:

[image: Div with Arrow]

**UPDATE**

This is the result I see with web-tiki proposed solution:

[image: web-tiki proposed solution]

See the cuts on the arrow?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: [This site](http://cssarrowplease.com/) could help.

Comment: I know that site but I do not have control over the height of the div ... It depends of the text inside. It might have one or two text rows. And in the site I need to specify the height in pixels.

Comment: If you have multiple rows, and an arrowhead with 45 degree angles, then it would eventually become very large (the width of the arrowhead must equal half the height).

Comment: Can we add this as an hover/active effect? I am working in a similar situation where I have a navbar which should look like an arrow when the link is active.

Answer (score 30):

---

**EDIT :**
If you need the arrow to adapt to the height of the text (considering it can display on several lines) You can use [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) background for the arrow.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yJkzu/12/)**

---

This can make it :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/2bQGS/62/)**

CSS :

```
div{
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
div:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
}
```

Comment: If you add two rows to the div this won't work ... And the arrow seems a little bit strange at least in FIREFOX. It shows some cuts in it ...

Comment: That div has a static height sir

Comment: @MDMoura if you need to manage a div with more than one line you should specifiy it in the question, since it's relevant constraint. have you also a min/max width?

Comment: @MDMoura what do you mean by cuts, In my firefox it looks perfect.

Comment: Now, I do not have a min or max width defined.

Comment: @web-tiki I just updated my question with the image of the result I get with your code ... You can see the cuts in the arrow.

Comment: @web-tiki It is nice but I still see the cuts in the arrow. Why is that?

Comment: @MDMoura It sounds like an antialiasing issue, but I can't help about that because I don't see it either in firefox or chrome (I am using firefox 28.0).

Comment: @MDMoura let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50792/discussion-between-web-tiki-and-mdmoura)

Answer (score 8):

**Check This**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jx99z/5/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="text">Some Text<span class="arrow"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.text {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    padding-left:4px;
}
.arrow {
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 0.20em;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;    /* Use font-size to control the size of the arrow. */
    font-size: 100px;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    background-color:#fff;   /* change background color acc to bg color */ 
    border-left-width: 0.2em;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #ff0000;
    left:0.25em;
}
```

Comment: Your code breaks when the div contains two or more text lines

Answer (score 7):

I know above answers are accurate, but give this a try also

You can use clip-path CSS

```
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 68%, 46% 100%, 0 68%);
```

Or you can also generate it from here: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Really nice method!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe is over your needs, but exists a solution, described in [**Pure CSS3 breadcrumb navigation**](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-breadcrumb-navigation), that allows to obtain boxes with arrow shape, stuck one inside each.

It is perfect for Breadcrumbs navigation and use another approach instead of simple `borders` to obtain desired result. More in detail, some CSS properties used are the following:

- **Generated content** ([support since **IE8**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent))
- **Box shadow** ([support since IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow))
- **2D Transformation** ([support since IE9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d))

Due to browsers support of these specific properties, this solution will work correctly since IE9 (not in IE8).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a very simple way to make it, but it uses transform so your target browser has to support that property (most up-to-date browsers do).

[image]

```css
body {
 padding-top: 95px;
}

.crumb-trail {
 background-color: #CCD2D8;
 color: #62717C;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 80%;
}

.crumb {
 padding: 4px 16px;
 position: relative;
}


.crumb:not(:last-child):before,
.crumb:not(:last-child):after {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 height: 1px;
 width: 17px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -7px;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.crumb:before {
 top: 6px;
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.crumb:after {
 bottom: 6px;
 -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
 transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BreadCrumbs</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="breadcrumbs.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <ul class="crumb-trail clearfix">
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Home
   </li>
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Forums
   </li>
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Search page
   </li>
   <li class="crumb pull-left">
    Preview: Search criteria
   </li>
  </ul>
  
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello great work you did there! though i'm stuck in one thing.. i want to change background color of first option "Home"..
can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Either use a first-child selector on .crumb or add a class to this section 
<li class="crumb pull-left">
  Home
</li>

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible:
in your html do somthing like this:

you have 2 divs one with class "arrow-right" and one with class "middle-div"

```
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
<div class="middle-div"></div>
```

in your css file do somthing like this:

```
.middle-div {
height: 120px;
float: right;
width: 230px;
background-color: green;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 110px;
 }

.arrow-right {
height: 0px;
    border-top: 60px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid green;
    float: right;
}
```

enjoy.. :)

Answer (score -4):

Try this code

```
  .arrow_box {
        position: relative;
        background: #88b7d5;
        border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
    }
    .arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
        left: 100%;
        top: 50%;
        border: solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .arrow_box:after {
        border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
        border-left-color: #88b7d5;
        border-width: 89px;
        margin-top: -89px;
    }
    .arrow_box:before {
        border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
        border-left-color: #c2e1f5;
        border-width: 95px;
        margin-top: -95px;
    }
```

Comment: Obviously you just pasted content at Batu Zet's recommendation without a single touch except sizes. Also there is no source reference. Please don't do this, it is very unrespectful.